# Android x86 (Lollipop 5.0.2) stuck on logo during boot

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google, android-x86, android-pc

I downloaded Android Lollipop x86 for my Toshiba Satellite L505D-S5965 and installation went perfectly. I pressed reboot when it was finished and the GRUB menu was there and I started Android. Everything worked perfectly until I got to the logo. I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1 to see if there was anything in the terminal but I found nothing.

**SIDENOTE**: I got my ISO from [this link](http://kickass.to/android-lollipop-x86-iso-file-rc-5-02-created-from-source-t10145528.html) since the Google Drive link doesn't work on my PC. It may or may not be broken. I tried it in VMware Workstation it did the same thing.

Comment: any development? I have the same problem with Android 5.1 In terminal I typed top -m 10 and I see that /system/bin/bootanimation takes almost 100% CPU but nothing else seems to be happening.

Comment: @Vitas Same problem to me. Any solutions ?

Comment: I gave up on trying Android in Virtualbox and found out that specialized emulators are much better. I used AmiDUOs since then and it works nicely.

Comment: [May be graphics card problem - check on android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/how-to-boot-the-android-x86-live-cd-when-you-have-problems-with-your-graphiccard)